# Aging nonprogrammer wants to hire someone to restore Gnus

Tags: gnus

I need, and am ready to pay for, help in restoring my Gnus, which I
had used for many years but has not worked since January.  I am not a
programmer, and am edging into senile dementia, so I would need
someone to take over the problem.  Someone I roused on help-gnu-emacs,
who had given me some advice, expressed willingness for a while, but
has stopped answering my emails.

I have used GNU Emacs since 1986, and Gnus since 2000.  At present I
use Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w-64-mingw32) under Cygwin (64 bit)
2.0.2(0.287/5/3) under Windows 10.0 Pro (64 bit), build 10240 (1511).
My ISP is Verizon, but, as a result of a deal Verizon made with AOL
when Verizon stopped handling email, AOL now handles my email though I
still have the Verizon address.

Thus, I need someone who understands both Gnus and AOL.

### Alternatively, is there an ISP I can switch to, that knows about &
supports Gnus and that is likely to last?

---  Joe Fineman    joe_f@verizon.net

||:  When you eat a berry, a bush is getting laid.  :||

Comment: I understand your frustration, but it is likely that your question will be closed: this is not an Emacs problem (despite Gnus being involved), it's a more general email problem; so it does not satisfy the guidelines for Emacs SE (there is already one vote to close the question). I would suggest  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/ as a possible recruitment platform for a consultant, but beware of scammers (not only on reddit). And you probably want to recruit someone local to you: the CS department at a local college might be able to provide some references. Good luck!

Comment: It should be possible to configure [GNUS with IMAP](https://gnus.org/manual/gnus_83.html):  From the [AOL web-page](https://help.aol.com/articles/how-do-i-use-other-email-applications-to-send-and-receive-my-aol-mail): IMAP  Incoming mail server (IMAP): imap.aol.com
 Outgoing mail server (SMTP): smtp.aol.com IMAP-993-SSL
SMTP-465-SSL

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.